# How to copy the selected value from one form input field to another form input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get the value from the form1 and submit on form2. Any suggestions how this could be achieved.

```html
<form action="/new"  method="POST" >
    
        <input  list="name" type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <datalist id="name">
            <option value="Hello">
            <option value="Hi">
        </datalist>
    <button>Submit</button> 
</form>

<form action="/new1" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="name" > 
    <-- I WANTED THE VALUE FROM FORM1 TO BE SUBMITTED ON FORM 2-->
</form>
```

Comment: You should first try it yourself and post attempts that did not work for you. Stackoverflow is not a place to get code for free.

Comment: Change the action of form1 so it becomes the action of form2 ?

Comment: I am just asking suggestions on how this could be achieved. I am stuck on this for a quite long time. and not asking for free code. If could help you can or just pass it. @molerat

Comment: form1 and form2 serves different puropse. I dont want the users to enter the name two times @Zyigh

Comment: @Ezhilan it was just sarcasm for "It's not clear what you really want...". If it's to store data in database, you could use a procedure. On your treatment page, you could duplicate the entry you need. On frontend page, you could listen to any change (or keypress) on you inputs and duplicate each field on the appropriate duplicate. In this case, you might need ajax to send the forms as you cannot send two forms at the same time with HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way, without jQuery:

```
<script>
function update(){
    let updateValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("name2").value = updateValue;
}
</script>

<form action="/new"  method="POST" >

<input  list="name" type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="update()">
<datalist id="name">
    <option value="Hello">
    <option value="Hi">
</datalist>
<button>Submit</button> 
</form>

<form action="/new1" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name2" value="name" > 
</form>
```

Comment: Worked fine.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add hidden input field in form2, and add change event on `#name` which is in form1. Once you change the value of `#name` it will append to form2 hidden field and then you can get the value of `id="fromForm1"` on form submit.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#name', function() {
    $('#fromForm1').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="/new"  method="POST" >
    <input list="name" type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <datalist id="name">
        <option value="Hello">
        <option value="Hi">
    </datalist>
    <button>Submit</button> 
</form>

<form action="/new1" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="name" >

    <!-- Added hidden input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="fromForm1" id="fromForm1">
</form>
```

Change type `hidden` to `text` in `<input type="hidden" name="fromForm1" id="fromForm1">`, if you want to see that it's working or not!

Comment: if you want to append form1 input value into `<input type="text" name="name" value="name" >` then replace `$('#fromForm1')` with your selector

Comment: May want to add a name to the hidden field.